# Изображение с canvas не сохраняется должным образом, просто пустое прозрачное изображение

Tags: javascript, php, canvas

Есть скрипт описанный на js который должен добавлять скриншот на canvas и отправлять его в обработчик php для дальнейшего сохранения. И этот скрипт работает почти хорошо, но первый скриншот всегда будет как пустое прозрачно изображение. На html форме допустим есть только canvas и php-обработчик.
js часть:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=> {
    function getBlob(evt,callback){
        if( evt.clipboardData == false || evt.clipboardData.items=='undefined' ){
            return false;
        };
        let items = evt.clipboardData.items;
        for( let i=0; i < items.length; i++){
            let item=items[i];
            if( ~item.type.indexOf('image') )callback( item.getAsFile() );
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('paste', function(e){
        let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const callback = function( blob ){
            if( blob ){
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
                img.onload = function() {
                    canvas.width=this.width;
                    canvas.height=this.height;
                    ctx.drawImage( img, 0, 0 );
                };
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        };
        getBlob( e, callback );
        let fd = new FormData();
        fd.append( 'imgs', canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace('data:image/png;base64,','') );
        fetch( location.href,{ method:'post', body:fd })
        .then( r=>r.text() )
        .then( text=>{
            //console.info('Screenshot %s saved',text );
            //alert('Скриншот сохранен');
        });
    });
});
```

php часть:

```
if(!empty($_POST['imgs'])) {
    $decoded = base64_decode(str_replace(' ', '+', $_POST['imgs']));
    $screenName = "screenshot" . rand() . ".png";
    $targetfile = "/mnt/ElmaFiles/" . $screenName;
    file_put_contents($targetfile, $decoded);
}
```

Помогите найти ошибку в коде.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изображение не успевает отрисоваться до отправки запроса, в итоге при второй вставке также работает неправильно, так как отправляет первое изображение. Можно сделать примерно так:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    function getBlob(evt, callback) {
        if (evt.clipboardData == false || evt.clipboardData.items == 'undefined') {
            return false;
        }
        let items = evt.clipboardData.items;
        for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            let item = items[i];
            if (~item.type.indexOf('image')) {
                callback(item.getAsFile());
            }
        }
    }

    function sendScreenshot(canvas) {
        let fd = new FormData();
        fd.append('imgs', canvas.toDataURL('image/png').replace('data:image/png;base64,', ''));
        fetch(location.href, {method: 'post', body: fd})
            .then(r => r.text())
            .then(text => {
                //console.info('Screenshot %s saved',text );
                //alert('Скриншот сохранен');
            });
    }

    window.addEventListener('paste', function (e) {

        let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
        let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        const callback = function (blob) {
            if (blob) {
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                img.crossOrigin = "anonymous";
                img.onload = function () {
                    canvas.width = this.width;
                    canvas.height = this.height;
                    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);//drawImage выполняется синхронно
                    sendScreenshot(canvas);
                    //sendScreenshot выполниться только после drawImage
                };
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        };
        getBlob(e, callback);
    });
});
```

Comment: Удивительно, как всё просто. Это работает, спасибо!